# Align div to the bottom of a container

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am using the **skeleton** CSS and I'm trying to get a `div` to be at the bottom of the page.
I have tried using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` within the container has a relative position, but the `div` just aligns to the right-hand side of the page.

```css
.page {
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">

<div class="page" id="home">
  <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="row">
      I am a title in the middle of the page.
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="">
      I want to be at the bottom of the page.
      <br>
      <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Bottom text element out of the CONTAINER parent and place it as a child of the PAGE element, then position:absolute will work:

https://jsfiddle.net/akLr6zb0/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">

<div class="page" id="home">
  <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="row">
      I am a title in the middle of the page.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom" style="">
    I want to be at the bottom of the page.
    <br>
    <a href="#">Click here!</a>
  </div>  
</div>

.page {
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#home {
  background: red;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: As simple as that! Embarrassing :-/ Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute; bottom: 0;` is right, but you also need to make sure the direct parent `.container` is the height of the page, and then center everything with `display: flex`:

```css
.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#home {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">

<div class="page" id="home">
  <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="row">
      I am a title in the middle of the page.
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
      I want to be at the bottom of the page.
      <br>
      <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's what you want but I achieve that with displaying the container as flex.

```css
.page {
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home {
  background: red;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">

<div class="page" id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      I am a title in the middle of the page.
    </div>
    <div class="row bottom" style="">
      I want to be at the bottom of the page.
      <br>
      <a href="#">Click here!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```